# Calculated Field - Count Of Number Above

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I am trying to create a calculated field to get the count >120 for the below field.

```
Week Employee  Date        Time Segment (Mins)   Total Output
Wk1      A    28/07/2019     FTD Seg 1              125
Wk1      A    28/07/2019     FTD Seg 2              20
Wk1      A    28/07/2019     FTD Seg 3              180
Wk1      B    28/07/2019     FTD Seg 1              66
Wk1      C    28/07/2019     FTD Seg 1              38
Wk1      C    28/07/2019     FTD Seg 2              119
Wk1      D    28/07/2019     FTD Seg 1              170
Wk2      B    29/07/2019     FTD Seg 1              136
Wk2      C    29/07/2019     FTD Seg 1              50
Wk2      D    29/07/2019     FTD Seg 1              200
Wk2      D    29/07/2019     FTD Seg 2              14
Wk2      D    29/07/2019     FTD Seg 3              35
```

I am using the following formula;

> =CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table A[Total Output]),FILTER(Table A,Table A[Total Output] >=120))

As per the above example the count would be 5. However, my formula returns a different value. I intend to pivot table the data and filter it by week, giving me a weekly count of outputs >120.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Also on a side note if anyone could point me in the right direction to learn how to put data into a table when posting i'd appreciate it.

Comment: "my formula returns a different value" - what is the value it returns? Your formula returned 5 when I tried it on your data sample.

Comment: To add data table, simply add it as text and then format as code sample - on the formatting toolbar, use {}

Comment: Thank you Rado, please see below for response.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. Based on the data sample you provided, you formula returns correct results. There must be something else that impacts your results but not mentioned in the question. If possible, upload your excel book online and share the link. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sharing the file. As I suspected, the data sample you posted in the question does not cover all scenarios in your model. You have 2 duplicates for Employee B, and when you are using "DISTINCTCOUNT", it eliminates them. That's why your results are different:

[image]

I recommend to fix it as follows:

First, create a measure to simply count Outputs:

```
Output Count = COUNT(Table A[Total Output])
```

Then, create another measure (I will call it "Large Output Count"; change it as you please):

```
Large Output Count = CALCULATE( [Output Count], Table A[Total Output] >=120)
```

This formula is more efficient than using FILTER.

Result:

[image]

Note: If these duplicates are a data error, I recommend you to eliminate them at the source, using Power Query. Don't try to write complex DAX to circumvent the problem.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! It didn't even cross my mind that it would be duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNTX(
    FILTER(
        VALUES( 'Table'[Total Output] ) , 
        [Total Output] >= 120 
    ) , [Total Output]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, if i create a pivot table and put 'Employee' in the row field and then 'count >120' in the values field, the count differs to when I double click the data, filter total output by value and manually count the >120.

Comment: Sorry! The following does what you want which is to count the distinct employee values where the parameters must meet the (120) plus criteria 

COUNTX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Output Value] >= 120 ),
        Table1[Employee Name]
    ),
    Table1[Employee Name]
)